# Fatal error utility not found in g++

Tags: macos, mojave, xcode, gcc

While I do make in a program I want to install, which installs fine in Opensuse, I get the error

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++
      standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
/Users/xyz/rivet/YODA-1.7.7/pyext/yoda/util.cpp:446:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found
#include <utility>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What I understand that it complains about not finding the utility library in c++ but for MacOS, the compiler is clang and it shows it has the file

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility
```

MacOS version is 10.14.6, and Xcode version is Version 11.0 (11A420a). How to solve this case then?

Comment: clang is not g++ e.g. it has different parameters. and OpenSuse is Linux not MacOS - You need to configure the build system to use the correct compiler and OS specific things, then it might work. Not every thing wrtitten for Linux works on macOS

Comment: I know OpenSuse is Linux, the point here to mention that the script works actually, and the exact script has worked on other Macs of my colleagues.

Comment: Then you need to include more info in the question  the obvious thing is how does your setup differ from your colleague?

Comment: That is what I don't know. The .profile file seems not to exist in my machine but there is a .bashrc. I am looking for any specific command in the .profile/.bashrc which can solve this issue.

Comment: We can't help without moie information - also more liekely to be an issue with your build system. g++ is odd to see ina macOS build unless you hgave installed gcc  by Macports, Homebrew etc or directly

Comment: When the compiler is built, it is configured to look in certain directories for header files and libraries. Run `g++ --print-search-dir` to see the configured paths. This should help you understand why it doesn't work on your Mac, but does on your colleagues.
And to fix it you can add an include path to the makefile, e.g. `-I/some/path`

Comment: What does `g++ --version` give on your machine and on working machines.

Comment: nB the command is `g++ --print-search-dirs` note the last s

Comment: @woolfie thanks for the suggestion. But what the solution was included in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in the warning message: pass `'-stdlib=libc++'` in the command line when you run the install command. So just add `CXX="g++ -stdlib=libc++"` to the install/make command.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple, yet hard to find: You need to set the environment variable `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 10.14 for Mojave and likely 10.15 for Catalina, like so

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14`

Thanks to @ChristophSchmidl who gave this hint at:

https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/3710#issuecomment-575627844